# Can a property be added to a method in a Javascript class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to create a class with a public method and add a property to that method for another function. From my understanding functions in javascript are just a special type of object so this should be possible, but I have not seen it done in the context of a class method.

I'll also note that I use typescript so I am trying to construct this class so that it will be strongly typed.

The end goal is to end up with something like this:

```js
const dataFetcher = new FetchData();
dataFetcher.fetch(); // fetches data synchronously
dataFetcher.fetch.async(); // fetches data asynchronously
```

I have tried a couple options with no success

Attempt 1:

```js
class FetchData {
    public fetch(): void {
        // fetch some data
    }
    fetch.async = (): Promise<void> => { // <-- this doesn't work
        // fetch same data asyncronously
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve());
    }
}
```

Attempt 2:

```js
interface IFetchFunction {
    (): void;
    async(): Promise<void>;
}

class FetchData {
    public test: IFetchFunction;
    constructor() {
        this.test = () => { // Typescript says the property "async" is missing on this method

        };
        this.test.async = () => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve());
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the function with the `async` property all at once with `Object.assign`. You'll also need to type the `async` function when you define it, since you want to specify that it resolves to `void` (not `unknown`, which is the default type):

```
interface IFetchFunction {
    (): void;
    async(): Promise<void>;
}

class FetchData {
    public test: IFetchFunction;
    constructor() {
        this.test = Object.assign(
            () => {

            },
            {
                async: (): Promise<void> => {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve());
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```